# How to return also json and render_template in Flask?

Tags: python, html, json, templates, flask

I've implemented a service in Python with Flask, to create the server. My service (MyService) take a query from the user and return a response, like a chatbot. So, i want to return both a text respons modifying the Html template, and a json containing response for using service as command line.
At the moment my service only return a render template,how I can do?

My app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/result", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       query = request.form['query']
       response = MyService.retrieve_response(query)
       return render_template("index.html", value=response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And my simple index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

<h2>Wellcome!</h2>

<form action="http://localhost:5000/result" method="POST">
  Make a question:<br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="query" id="query">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>


<br>
<h3>Response is: </h3>
<br>
{{value}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks like it should work to me, could you try and re-explain what's not working?

Comment: Now my app return only a render_template, I want to return both a json and a render_template.

Answer (score 8):

You can branch out your return based on request type. If the request is for html text, return the render_template. If the request is for json, return json. For example:

```
@app.route("/result", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       query = request.form['query']
       response = MyService.retrieve_response(query)
       if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
           return jsonify(...)
       return render_template("index.html", value=response)
```

Answer (score 6):

@dvnguyen's answer is good, but you might consider creating different routes for html and for json.  For example:

```
@app.route("/web/result")
def result_html():
   response = MyService.retrieve_response()
   return render_template("index.html", value=response)

@app.route("/api/result")
def result_json():
   response = MyService.retrieve_response()
   return jsonify(response)
```

The /api or /web prefix makes the intention clear, and also simplifies unit testing.